# Suggestion for a custom drop ship scenario

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, dropshipping

I'm working with a client to build a store with a somewhat unique dropship style set up:

- We will keep some stock at a warehouse which is our buffer stock level.
- When a shopper purchases item(s), an order email is to be sent both to the store owner and the warehouse.
- Warehouse will dispatch the items.
- A daily digest email of all the items sold will then need to be sent to the manufacturer of the goods. They will dispatch the items to the ware house to replenish the buffer stock. But we want the order email tot he manufacturer to be stripped of any shopper's information.

Before we start considering an original solution, are there any extensions on the market that be configured to do this, (or with some modification).

Or would this need to be a ground up job?

Thanks

Comment: `When the shopper purhcased an item an order email is sent to both the store owner and the warehouse`. I assume that this email is only sent to the warehouse when the order is fully cleared with payment taken? This all sounds very possible, but I dont believe I know of any extension that will cover all your requirements.

Comment: [There are several extensions at Magento Connect which satisfy most or all of your requirements](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=dropship&pl=0).

Your spec as you state it here sounds a bit incomplete - for example, do you expect the system to help with stock on hand vs. dropshipped stock? Who is responsible for updating processed orders? Etc...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I had a brief look over them and it would appear they all need some level of modification but that was what we expected.
Stock reconciliation is done manually and the store does not display an real time stock level to the shopper (virtually It's always in stock, and operate on a Just In Time model).
The shop owner is responsible for updating processed orders from emails by the warehouse when an order is dispatched.